# How to limit parallel jobs

Tags: bash, expect

I have a hosts containing file say `/tmp/hostlist` which requires username & password to login and I am using expect command to login hosts and execute command and come out like below in my bash script.

```
)

VAR=$(expect -c "$script")

echo "$VAR" >/tmp/outexp
-----------------
```

I am able to handle parallel execution -

```
while IFS= read -r i
do
        ( export server_name=`echo $i`;echo "connecting to $i";expect -c 
wait
```

Is there a way to limit no. of hosts at a time? e.g suppose i have 1000 hosts in a file..and i want to execute in a set of 100 hosts at a time to complete 1000 hosts..

Comment: It would be simpler to loop over the hostlist in the bash part, and execute expect in the background for each iteration.

Comment: @glennjackman  thanks I handle parallel execution with while loop and updated my question. Is there a way to limit no. of hosts at a time? e.g suppose i have 1000 hosts in a file..and i want to execute in a set of 100 hosts at a time to complete 1000 hosts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU Parallel you would do something like:

```bsh
[compute $script]
export script
run_one() {
  i="$1"
  export server_name=`echo $i`
  echo "connecting to $i"
  expect -c "$script"
  echo "Job completed on $i"
  echo "-----------------------------------"
}
export -f run_one

cat "$file" | parallel -j100 run_one '2>&1' >"$log2"
```

Or:

```bsh
[compute $script]
export script

cat "$file" |
  parallel -j100 --tag 'i={} expect -c "$script" 2>&1' >"$log2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many jobs are running and wait until they are finished.

Here is a sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [[ $i -lt 50 ]]; do

    n=$(jobs | grep Running | wc -l)
    if [[ $n -ge 10 ]]; then
        echo "waiting for jobs to finish ($n running)"
        sleep 1
    else
        echo start next $i
        bash -c "sleep $(( $RANDOM % 3 )); echo $i finished" &
        let i+=1
    fi
done
wait
```

You would use it like this to limit it to 100 hosts in parallel:

```
while IFS= read -r i
do
    n=$(jobs | grep Running | wc -l)
    if [[ $n -ge 100 ]]; then
        echo "waiting for jobs to finish ($n running)"
        sleep 1
    else
        ( export server_name=`echo $i`;echo "connecting to $i";expect -c "$script";echo "Job completed on $i";echo "-----------------------------------" ) >> "${log}_${i}" 2>&1 &
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: my requirement is to read hostlist file - start with 100 hosts , then next 100 ..... this should be automated

Comment: @Sin15 Did you try the solution? This limits the number of jobs running in parallel to 100. Why do you want to wait for all 100 to complete before starting with the next 100?

Comment: bcoz the files "${log}_${i}" is getting generate, so the no. of hosts = no. of files will get generate to execute in parallel, so once 100 hosts completes, contents of all files will get redirect to common file and remove 1oo files and then next 100 hosts start and process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a somewhat different approach that does not rely on you keeping track of the number of subprocesses you spawn and whenever the queue is lower than your maximum it fills up

```bsh
max_jobs=100 # set queue size
while IFS= read -r i; do
  num_jobs=$(pgrep -c -P$$)
  if [[ $num_jobs -ge $max_jobs ]]; then
    wait -n $(pgrep -P$$) # Wait until a any subprocess terminates
  else
    <calling_awesome_script_here> &
  fi
done < "$file"
```